# Wireless AP suddenly stopped working and is non-responsive

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, openwrt

I have a TP-Link RE450 configured as a OpenWRT dumb AP running in the upstairs of my house; its IP is `192.168.1.11`. Last night, the two wifi networks it broadcasts (one 2.4G, one 5G) suddenly stopped allowing any device to connect to it, even though both networks still show up on the list of available wifis. I both hard and soft restarted the device several times, no help.

The AP downstairs still works fine, and allows me to connect to the internet, so I know it's not an issue with the WAN.

I tried `ping 192.168.1.11` and all packets are dropped, with the reply being `Destination Host Unreachable`, and `nmap 192.168.1.11` also confirms the host is down.

I have not touched the AP for months, and no one else in the house knows much about networking, so they definitely did not mess with it either. So what could possibly have caused this? Any diagnostic advice? Perhaps just hardware failure? Though all LEDs on the AP are lit normally with no signs of errors.

Comment: Hardware failure.  Unplug the device and let it cool down for at least a few hours and then give it a try.  Otherwise replace it. Merry Xmas

Comment: @cliff2310 oh haha... thanks for the confirmation. Merry Christmas!

Comment: hi, have you Verify Cables Are Securely Connected? or it could be a hardware problem

Comment: @GloriaGu yes thanks for that reminder, it was a wire connection issue (of a sort) after all

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, the actually problem was with the powerline adapter (which I didn't mention originally) the upstairs AP was connected to. For unknown reasons, the powerline adapter pair lost their network connection, leading to the AP upstairs still being functional on its own, but not connected to the router downstairs.